# Form not Rendered in Django

Tags: html, django, python-2.7, django-forms

I am trying to display a form in Django HTML Template, but it is not being Rendered

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Description, Bill
from django.http import Http404
from .forms import DForm
from .forms import BForm
import pprint
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
 context = {}
 return render(request, 'front/index.html', context)



def commitbill(request):
 if request.method == "POST":
    form = BForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        print form.errors
        Bill = form.save()
        return HttpResponse(str(Bill.bill_id()))
    print form.errors
    return HttpResponse("fail")
```

forms.py

```
   from django import forms

   from .models import Description, Bill

   class BForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
     db_table = 'inventory_bill'
     model = Bill
     fields = ('party', 'inovice', 'amount','image','image_caption')
```

the template, portion of which is not being Rendered!

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
 <head>

    <title></title>
    <link href="{%static "./styles/bootstrap.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" />
 </head>
 <body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Rahul's Shop</h1>
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Inventory</h2>
    <form id="bill" action ="{% url 'front:commitbill' %}" method = "post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     {% csrf token %}
     {{ form.as_p }}
     <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <input type="button" id="add_items" class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-2  btn btn-success" value="Add items" \>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

The portion {{ form.as_p }} is not being Rendered, That's my main Issue!

Comment: You need to pass the form as part of your response context in your view. See this example from the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#the-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your index should read like this, you need to pass the form to the template context.

```
def index(request):
 form = BForm()
 context = {
  'form': form,
 }
 return render(request, 'front/index.html', context)
```